# JQuery/Javascript Find and delete nav (having same id) with less li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with a CMS that generates 2 navs

```
<!-- Nav 121 -->
<nav class="clearfix clear" id="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="navigation clearfix" id="nav" role="navigation">
        <li class="right-menu-heading mobile"> 
      <span class="text">Page title</span>
        </li>
        <li> more list elements than the other </li>
        <li> more list elements than the other </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and the other nav

```
<!-- Nav 120 -->
<nav class="clearfix clear" id="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="navigation clearfix" id="nav" role="navigation">
        <li class="right-menu-heading mobile""> 
      <span class="text">Page title</span>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

One nav has more elements than the other, they have the same structure and the same class and id's.
The only thing distinguishing them is 
the comment above the code and one having more li elements than the other.

I am trying to completely delete the nav with less li elements.. as it creates problems further down the code, but i havent had any luck so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Same IDs is invalid HTML. It would be good to rely just on a common `class`

Comment: As Shaunak D said, the HTML is invalid and you shouldn't try to solve it on the client-side. It would be better to find out why it is being generated twice and eliminate the problem server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the length of lis in each nav, and then find nav with least li, and remove it.

```js
var arr = new Array();
$("nav").each(function(i,v) {
   arr[i] = $(this).find("ul li").length;
})

var highest = 0;
var highest_key = 0;

$.each(arr, function(key, value) {
    if (value > highest) { highest = value; highest_key = key;  } ;
});

$('nav:eq('+(highest_key+1)+')').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Nav 121 -->
<nav class="clearfix clear" id="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="navigation clearfix" id="nav" role="navigation">
        <li class="right-menu-heading mobile"> 
      <span class="text">Page title</span>
        </li>
        <li> more list elements than the other </li>
        <li> more list elements than the other </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<!-- Nav 120 -->
<nav class="clearfix clear" id="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="navigation clearfix" id="nav" role="navigation">
        <li class="right-menu-heading mobile"> 
            <span class="text">Page title</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Same `ids` on DOM is not valid HTML.

But here is a fiddle how you can solve your issue:

```js
function clearNavigations() {
   var listItemsCtn = 0, listItemsCtn = 0, $largestNav;
 
   $('nav').each(function() {
    var $nav = $(this);
    var curListItemsCtn = $nav.find('ul').children('li').length; 
     
    if(curListItemsCtn > listItemsCtn) {
      $largestNav = $nav;
    }
 
    listItemsCtn = curListItemsCtn;
  });

  if($largestNav) {
    $('nav').not($largestNav).remove();
  }
}

// run onDOMready or after your navigations!
clearNavigations();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Nav 121 -->
<nav class="clearfix clear" id="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="navigation clearfix" id="nav" role="navigation">
        <li class="right-menu-heading mobile"> 
      <span class="text">Page title</span>
        </li>
        <li> more list elements than the other </li>
        <li> more list elements than the other </li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<!-- Nav 120 -->
<nav class="clearfix clear" id="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="navigation clearfix" id="nav" role="navigation">
        <li class="right-menu-heading mobile"> 
      <span class="text">Page title</span>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier if you change classes, ids, but if you don't have access and you have to use as it is

```
$('nav.clearfix.clear > ul:first').addClass('stackoverflow');
($('nav.clearfix.clear > ul.stackoverflow li').size() > $('nav.clearfix.clear > ul:not(.stackoverflow) li').size())?$('nav.clearfix.clear > ul:not(.stackoverflow)').parent().remove():$('nav.clearfix.clear > ul.stackoverflow').parent().remove();
```

After this code you will keep the nav which has more elements.